# How to get the max of a sum?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can anyone tell me how do I get the Max of a calculated field? Below is an image of my situation:

[image: Table Structure][image: Grouping Pic]

Note that Flag is of type `int`.

I want to write the expression in the image , but when I use it, it kinda does:

```
Sum(Sum(Fields!Flag.value))
```

Can anyone help me out on this. I think I need to add scope for the `Sum(Flag)` but when I add the group scope as EMPID as:

```
=iif(SUM(Fields!Flag.value,"Fields!EmpID.Value")>2,"RED",nothing)
```

It throws me an error saying something about the scope.

**EDIT:**

I need attendance of each employees. FLAG is basically 1 if absent and 0 if anything else.

The bottom row(Flag,Date,Status,Comment). Now I have an alert There:

```
=iif(Fields!Flag.Value=1,"RED",Nothing)
```

Beside the Textbox(Textbox62) in middle row(EmpID,EmpName) I did Expression:SUM(Flag) and in the Fill section in Text Box Properties i have done:

```
=iif(SUM(Fields!Flag.value,"Fields!EmpID.Value")>2,"RED",nothing)
```

So the above expression creates an alert if employee is absent more than 3 days.

The top most row(Department,Manager) can be drilled down for to see more detailed view of the report. Now my problem is, in the column (FLAG) i need to create a Background color change if any employee in a particular department is absent more than 3 days.so that we do not have to drill down all the departments in order see if any employee is absent or not. 
So my approach was to see the Max(Sum(Flag))>2 then create color change. I tried:

```
=iif(MAX(Sum(Fields!Flag.Value))>2,"Red",Nothing)
```

It does not work at the Department level as it basically considers (SUM(Sum(Flag))).

Thanks................

Comment: *"an error saying something about the scope"*... well, what was that "something", and what did you do with it? :)

Comment: The value expression for the 'TextBox62' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. It says that the scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group or name of a dataset or name of a containing data region.

Comment: What that error means is that you need to use the name of either a GROUP, DATASET or DATA REGION as the scope. You have used the name of a field in the dataset. Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve - do you want the max value for ALL employees, or for each Manager or Department?

Comment: What about `=iif(MAX(SUM(Fields!Flag.value,"EmpID"))>2,"RED",nothing)`

Comment: Disaster strikes again... This does not work in SSRS 2008. It basically says aggregate of aggregate not possible.. can anyone please tell me how to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the scope of an aggregate, it is assumed that you are using the current scope. For example, when you say

```
Sum(Fields!Flag.value)
```

It is interpreted as something like

```
Sum(Fields!Flag.value, "EmpID")
```

**The scope is the name of the Group, not the name of a dataset field.**
Depending on where it is in the table. When you want to say something like

```
Sum(Sum(Fields!Flag.value))
```

You need to specify the scope for each one that isn't going to be the current default.
In your case you should use something like this:

```
=iif(MAX(SUM(Fields!Flag.value, "EmpID"), "Department")>2,"RED",nothing)
```

Again, pay attention to which group each aggregate is referring to and where the expression is on the table.

Also, this expression in a textbox will just make the word "RED" appear in the box. If you want it to change the color, you have to put it in the "Fill color" expression in the properties.

Comment: Hey Steven,Thank you for the Reply. But somehow this does nt seem to work with SSRS 2008 or below. It throws an error saying that we cannot use Aggregate of an Aggregate. Can you please let me know if there is anything that I can do about it.

Comment: It works in 2008 for me. I'll need more details to help you. Please post the expression you are using, where you put it, and the exact error message.

Comment: This is the error message I got " The BackgroundColor expression for the text box 'Textbox59' contains an aggregate function (or RunningValue or RowNumber functions) in the argument to another aggregate function (or RunningValue).  Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other aggregate functions.
Build complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings "

Comment: Expression(TextBox 59): =iif(MAX(SUM(Fields!Flag.value, "EmpID"), "Department")>2,"RED",nothing)

Comment: Try =iif(MAX(SUM(Fields!Flag.value, "Details"), "EmpID")>2,"RED",nothing)

Comment: Hello Steven, Aggregate of Aggregate works in SSRS 2008 R2 but not in SSRS 2008.